# fail to install mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to setup a not so old (but still few years) of Rails project on new Mavericks machine.
When I try to `bundle`, i keep getting this error (sorry for the long code):

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/royzinn/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/royzinn/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/royzinn/dailyd/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18 for     inspection.
Results logged to /Users/royzinn/dailyd/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Before that I had a message saying that the gem was built for MySQL version 5.5.20 and that I have already activated other (more advanced) MySQL.

I "cleaned" everything with Homebrew, tried to reinstall but nothing seems to work.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Oh man when I upgraded to Mavericks I had a zillion issues.  Does `brew install mysql` work?  If so can you boot it? `mysql.sever restart` ?

Comment: The problem is related to providing the header C files from the MySQL connection driver. There are similar issues in the net about this. Look one solution for your specific OS. I have dealt with this problem in Ubuntu and Windows and the solution was *basically* the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete this directory :

```
/Users/royzinn/dailyd/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.18
```

If this doesn't help delete rvm directory and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the gem can compile on installation.

```
gem install mysql
```

If you get an error that the gem won't compile, it may be necessary to install MySQL where Bundler can find it--even though it is included with OS X. Rather than passing paths as arguments to Bundler, just install MySQL with Homebrew and then install the gem.

```
brew install mysql
gem install mysql2
```

Finally, the mysql2 gem's version is probably out of date in the Gemfile and needs to be updated.

```
bundle update mysql2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a while ago, but as far as I remember, uninstalling everything and then reinstalling with homebrew just worked :-)